# Banach spaces locally having a basis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The $\mathcal{L}_p$-spaces ($1\leq p \leq \infty$) are Banach spaces $X$  such that there exists a constant $\lambda$ so that every finite dimensional subspace $E$ of $X$ is contained in another finite dimensional subspace $F$ which is $\lambda$-isomorphic to $\ell_p^n$.

Let us say that a Banach space $X$ *locally admits a basis* if there exists a constant $\lambda$ so that every finite dimensional subspace $E$ of $X$ is contained in another finite dimensional subspace $F$ admitting a basis with basis constant $\leq \lambda$.

Each $\mathcal{L}_p$-space locally admits a basis, and it is not difficult to show that if $X$ has a basis then it locally admits a basis.

**Questions.**

1. Suppose that $X$ is separable and locally admits a basis. Does $X$ have a basis?
2. Suppose that $X$ is separable. Does $X$ locally admit a basis?

The answer to Question 1 is positive for $\mathcal{L}_p$-spaces.

Comment: Professor Gonzalez, as far as I can remember, both questions have a negative answer in Szarek's paper where he provided a space with BAP & without a basis.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I have looked at Szarek's paper. I think you should write an answer, trying to say something about the second question using Kalton's review in MathScinet to one of Pujara's papers.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an access to MathSciNet, and I don't have a copy of Kalton's review in another form. Presently I can record here the exact reference to Szarek's article https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02392555  Corollary 1.6 within nicely sums up the answers to both questions -- for future visitors to this MO post.

Comment: Szarek's result aside, perhaps Enflo's space is another example of a separable space with local basis structure (by Proposition 1.3 in https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02392555) & without basis?

Comment: MR0399819 (53 #3661) Reviewed
Pujara, Lakhpat R.
Some local structures in Banach spaces.
Math. Japon. 20 (1975), no. 1, 49–54.
46B15

Comment: The author defines a notion of local basic structure for a Banach space, 
by analogy with the concept of local unconditional structure. 
A Banach space X has the "λ-finite dimensional subspaces basis property'' 
(λ-f.d.s.b.) if every finite-dimensional subspace can be embedded in a 
finite-dimensional subspace with a basis of basis constant at most λ; 
X is a B_λ-space if, in addition, this subspace can be chosen to be 
complemented with projection constant at most λ.

Comment: Some elementary properties of these concepts are established, and the 
behaviour of B_λ-condition under duality is studied. It does not seem to be known whether every Banach space has the λ-f.d.s.b. 
for some λ≥1.
Reviewed by N. J. Kalton

Comment: The key is the last phrase of the review.

Comment: Szarek's negative answer to question 2 is a hard result, but it is not so difficult to give a negative answer to question 1 once you know that there is a subspace of $c_0$ that fails the approximation property: If $c_0$ is finitely representable in $X$, then $X$ has local basis structure. This is a consequence of the fact that every finite dimensional space is $2$-complemented in a finite dimensional space that has a basis with basis constant at most $2$.

Comment: @Onur Oktay: I missunderstood your first comment. I thought that only the first question was answered in Szarek's paper.

Comment: It would be nice if you write an answer indicating how Szarek's results answer both questions.

Comment: Professor @M.González , I hope the answer below serves the purpose & is somewhat beneficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of this post is to make an expanded summary of the comments to OP on request of Professor Gonzalez.

Local basis structure (LBS) was considered by Pujara in 1975 under a different name as pointed out by Prof. Gonzalez in his [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466498/banach-spaces-locally-having-a-basis?noredirect=1#comment1211074_466498) .
To the best of my knowledge, both questions were answered negatively by Szarek in 1987. The snippet below is from [[Szarek1987](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02392555)].

[image]

Imho, the main actor in Szarek's construction is the space $(\bigoplus Y_{p_k}^{n_k})_{\ell^2}$ that lacks LBS, where $Y_p^n$ are carefully chosen $n$-dimensional subspaces of $L^p$ (Proposition 3.1) and $p_k\to 2$, $n_k\to\infty$ are carefully chosen sequences (Proposition 4.1). It is worth to note Remark 5.1 that points out other nonreflexive examples, cf. Professor Bill Johnson's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466498/banach-spaces-locally-having-a-basis?noredirect=1#comment1211110_466498).

[image]

Perhaps Szarek's construction should be read along with the asymptotically Hilbertian spaces in [[CasazzaGarciaJohnson2001](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-01-06142-1)].

For the future visitors to this post: interested reader should pay attention to the type and cotype of the constructed spaces in both articles.